Set size limt to direct upload to azure blob storage via SAS URL
I have my Frontend Application that received SAS URL to do a direct upload to
azure blob storage container. However upon generating SAS URL, I can't find a way to set a size limit to the uploaded.
here is a sample code
    const sasPermissions = new ContainerSASPermissions();
    sasPermissions.write = true; // Allow write permissions
   
    // Generate SAS query parameters
    const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
      containerName,
      blobName,
      protocol: 'https',
      permissions: sasPermissions,
      expiresOn: expiryDate
    }, sharedKeyCredential).toString();

    // Construct SAS URL
    const sasUrl = `${blockBlobClient.url}?${sasToken}`;
    return sasUrl



Set size limt to direct upload to azure blob storage via SAS URL

According to this MS Q&A by   Sumarigo-MSFT.
Azure Blob Storage doesn't directly support to set a file size limit directly within a Shared Access Signature (SAS).
Instead, you can enforce a file size limit by adding a check in your application code before you create the SAS.
In my environment, I created Frontend Code with set the size of file limit Like below:
Code:
document.getElementById('uploadButton').addEventListener('click', async () => {
    const fileInput = document.getElementById('fileInput');
    const file = fileInput.files[0];
    const maxSizeInMB = 5; // Maximum file size in megabytes

    if (file && file.size > maxSizeInMB * 1024 * 1024) {
        alert(`File size exceeds the limit of ${maxSizeInMB}MB.`);
        return;
    }

    try {
        // Request SAS URL from the server
        const response = await fetch(`/generate-sas-url?blobName=${file.name}`);
        const data = await response.json();
        const sasUrl = data.sasUrl;

        // Perform the upload using fetch API
        const uploadResponse = await fetch(sasUrl, {
            method: 'PUT',
            headers: {
                'x-ms-blob-type': 'BlockBlob' // Required for blob uploads
            },
            body: file
        });

        if (uploadResponse.ok) {
            console.log(`Upload block blob ${file.name} successfully`);
        } else {
            console.error('Error uploading file:', uploadResponse.statusText);
        }
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error uploading file:', error.message);
    }
});

In my environment, I set an limit of 5MB file size.
Backend script:
// server.js
const express = require('express');
const { generateBlobSASQueryParameters, ContainerSASPermissions,StorageSharedKeyCredential } = require('@azure/storage-blob');

const app = express();
const port = 3000;

// Configure your Azure Storage credentials
const accountName = 'venkat326123';
const accountKey = 'T3czZpu1gZ0nLKiCuli9a6txxxxx=';
const sharedKeyCredential = new StorageSharedKeyCredential(accountName, accountKey);
const containerName = 'venkat';

app.use(express.static('public')); // Serve static files from 'public' directory

app.get('/generate-sas-url', (req, res) => {
    const blobName = req.query.blobName;
    const expiryDate = new Date(new Date().valueOf() + 3600 * 1000); // 1 hour expiration

    const sasPermissions = new ContainerSASPermissions();
    sasPermissions.write = true; // Allow write permissions

    const sasToken = generateBlobSASQueryParameters({
        containerName,
        blobName,
        protocol: 'https',
        permissions: sasPermissions,
        expiresOn: expiryDate
    }, sharedKeyCredential).toString();

    const sasUrl = `https://${accountName}.blob.core.windows.net/${containerName}/${blobName}?${sasToken}`;
    res.json({ sasUrl });
});

app.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`Server running at http://localhost:${port}`);
});

Output:
If the file size is above 5MB it will show warning before uploading.

Portal:

If the file size is below 5MB it will upload in Azure Blob Storage.
